# Call Stored Procedure com JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, stored-procedures, spring-data

Preciso chamar a seguinte procedure abaixo, so que os projetos da empresa utilizam *JPA 2.0* e todos os exemplos que encontro são para *JPA 2.1 +*.

```
prc_performance_vendas_obter(vdataini => :vdataini,
                           vdatafim => :vdatafim,
                           vrefcursor => :vrefcursor)
```

O meu maior problema é o que devo passar como parametro para o **vrefcursor**, no 2.1 existe uma enum *ParameterMode* onde existem os tipos IN, OUT... para serem selecionados, só que aqui não encontrei nada para o 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Execução de Store Procedure no JPA 2.0 não é possível através de métodos prontos, como pode ver [neste link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures_in_JPA_2.0).

> JPA 2.0 does not have any direct support for stored procedures.

O que você pode fazer é tentar executar a Store Procedure através de Native Query, desta forma em um banco Oracle, como no exemplo do link:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN prc_performance_vendas_obter(vdatain => ?, vdatafim => ?, vrefcursor => ?); END;");
query.setParameter(1, dataIni);
query.setParameter(2, dataFim);
query.setParameter(3, refCursor);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Ou para obter resultados:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN prc_performance_vendas_obter(vdatain => ?, vdatafim => ?, vrefcursor => ?); END;", Vendas.class);
query.setParameter(1, dataIni);
query.setParameter(2, dataFim);
query.setParameter(3, refCursor);
List<Venda> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: o problema não esta em executar a proc, e sim passar o parametro da proc (refCursor) q é um tipo cursor, no jpa 2.1 existe uma enum q passo como parametro, so que no 2.0 não achei o devo passar como parametro

Answer (score 0):

O JPA 2.0 não possui suporte explícito para stored procedures (o JPA 2.1 possui). 
Uma solução alternativa é usar consultas nativas (como {CALL APURARCAMPANHASBRINDES.PROC_APURARCAMPANHA(?1,?2, ?3,  ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7)}), 
mas isso não funciona quando a procedure possui parâmetros externos. Aqui está uma implementação de exemplo que usa a interface Work do Hibernate.

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class CampanhaBrindesStoredProcedure {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private String mensagem;
    private String geroubrinde;

    @Transactional
    public void apurarCampamha(Long numeroPedido, String codigoFilialNF, String cgcEntCGCENT, Long numeroSequencia,
            String integradora)  {
        try {
            MyStoredProc storedProc = new MyStoredProc(numeroPedido, codigoFilialNF, cgcEntCGCENT, numeroSequencia,
                    integradora);
            entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).doWork(storedProc);
            setGeroubrinde(storedProc.getGeroubrinde());
            setMensagem(storedProc.getMensagem());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getGeroubrinde() {
        return geroubrinde;
    }

    public void setGeroubrinde(String geroubrinde) {
        this.geroubrinde = geroubrinde;
    }

    public String getMensagem() {
        return mensagem;
    }

    public void setMensagem(String mensagem) {
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
    }

    private static final class MyStoredProc implements Work {

        private final Long numeroPedido;
        private final String codigoFilialNF;
        private final String cgcEntCGCENT;
        private final Long numeroSequencia;
        private final String integradora;
        private String mensagem;
        private String geroubrinde;

        private MyStoredProc(Long numeroPedido, String codigoFilialNF, String cgcEntCGCENT, Long numeroSequencia,
                String integradora) {
            this.numeroPedido = numeroPedido;
            this.codigoFilialNF = codigoFilialNF;
            this.cgcEntCGCENT = cgcEntCGCENT;
            this.numeroSequencia = numeroSequencia;
            this.integradora = integradora;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            try (CallableStatement stmt = conn
                    .prepareCall("{CALL APURARCAMPANHASBRINDES.PROC_APURARCAMPANHA(?1, ?2, ?3,  ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7)}")) {
                stmt.setLong(1, numeroPedido);
                stmt.setString(2, codigoFilialNF);
                stmt.setString(3, cgcEntCGCENT);
                stmt.setLong(4, numeroSequencia);
                stmt.setString(5, integradora);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                mensagem = stmt.getString(6);
                geroubrinde = stmt.getString(7);
                if (stmt.wasNull()) {
                    geroubrinde = null;
                    mensagem = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public String getMensagem() {
            return mensagem;
        }

        public String getGeroubrinde() {
            return geroubrinde;
        }
    }
}
```